# I Answered A Question For Nothing!

Tags: discussion, support, answers, reputation

I once answered a question, and it appeared second in the list of answers. The answer is a good one, because I provided a M.C.V.E. and it's fairly straightforward.

But the asker of the question decided not to bother with his question anymore. The asker isn't accepting an answer, he/she just left the question alone.

I spent my time researching the answer to a difficult question, and I didn't get anything? I've just answered a question for nothing. If you don't get anything in return for a great answer, then I might as well not answer at all.

And you know what I answer for? More reputation.

Comment: That is how this site works. But I'm not sure if I fully grasp your point as you seem to have gathered 541 reputation. some of which are from votes on posts....

Comment: So you've decided it is a problem that someone answers and it doesn't get upvotes.  And this is, for some reason, a serious problem  What exactly do you want to happen?  Do you want automatic upvotes for simply answering a question?  How do you know the answer is even good enough to get upvotes?  What if an answer is wrong.

Comment: I mean, the asker isn't doing anything to the question anymore.

Comment: @NarawaGames so your problem is the asker abandoned the question and didn't upvote or accept?

Comment: He didn't accept any answer at all, and he hasn't done anything to the question.

Comment: *"I'd seriously consider not answering at all"* - that's fair enough, if you were only answering for the upvotes and accepts.

Comment: Stick with down/close voting crap.  It's much easier than finding, and answering, good questions.

Comment: _The asker isn't accepting any more answers_ - What do you mean, accepting **more** answers? The Asker can only accept one and if they've already accepted an answer, why should they do anything with subsequent answers?

Comment: Welcome to charity, where you give and should not expect anything in return.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It happens.**  More often than you think, too.

There are a number of reasons why your answer doesn't get upvoted:

- It's incomplete (it touches on the problem, but doesn't really *explain* things)
- A better answer exists on the question
- The potential upvoters lost their internet connection *just* as they were going to look at your answer
- The Earth moves towards perihelion
- [Tim loses his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Answer acceptance has always existed **for the OP**.  It's up to them to determine what's helped them best.  The community then decides which one is correct by voting on it.

If you're upset about this, you can do a few things to improve this:

- Improve your answer; make it so that it stands well above the rest.
- Improve the **question** so that it reads clearer, and has the potential to get more eyes looking at it.
- Clarify your answer; remove any ambiguities and confusion that may exist while reading it.
- Explore alternative ways to solve the problem
- ...or, find another question to answer. You can't get upvotes on *every* question you answer, and that may be due to any number of reasons above.

Comment: You forgot about [Tim losing his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) **again** right before someone decided to upvote

Comment: Damn it Tim, quit losing your keys every time someone wants an upvote.

Comment: Didn't know about the perihelion....

Comment: @rene:  Yeah, it's too hot so I couldn't be bothered to upvote.  Something along those lines.

Comment: an option worth mentioning is editing the question to improve it; this increases chances for answerer to get upvotes in several ways. There are even [badges to incentivise successful edits like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/edit-and-answer-badges/info)